# Make control-click behave like right-click on a JList

Tags: java, swing, contextmenu, selection, jlist

I'm writing a swing application on Mac OS and want to have my context menus on a JList appear when I ctrl-click as well as when I right-click. The problem now is that ctrl-click always clears the selection which is not what I want (imagine a context menu in a file browser letting the user delete the selected files).

Is there a simple way to make the ctrl-click behave like a right-click in terms of the selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to achieve this: use [`setComponentPopupMenu`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu%28javax.swing.JPopupMenu%29), it will take care of all the extra work and OS-specific right-click issues.

I tested on both Windows and Mac (and it works):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestJPopup {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestJPopup.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem("One"));
        popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Two"));
        popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Three"));
        JList list = new JList(new String[] { "Hello", "World", "Something", "Else", "Out", "Of", "Ideas" });
        list.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
        frame.add(list);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestJPopup().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Alternatively (but it seems useless), you can use the method `java.awt.event.MouseEvent.isPopupTrigger()` to know if you should display a `JPopupMenu` or not.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that this won't work so easily in my particular case as I am building my menu dynamically depending on the current selection. I would have to reorganize my code so that it rebuilds the menu when the selection changes. I will look into that.